# Логично ли использовать современные технологии (типа CSS3), верстая под IE9+, в той части кода, которая предназначенной для мобильных устройств?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, css3

В частности, есть необходимость реализовать всплывающее боковое меню для смартфонов. Как вариант - использовать переходы. Вот и подумал, что раз дело касается гаджетов, думать о IE9 Не нужно. Ход мысли правильный, или среди гаджетов есть какие-то звери, которые не поймут CSS3 (префиксы ставлю автоматом)?
Поделитесь мыслями, дамы и господа.

Comment: хз, я бы не парился за мобилку в таком случае))

Comment: Знаете такой ресурс: caniuse.com? Идем и смотрим [css transition](https://caniuse.com/#search=css%20transition), только выберите "tracked mobile" в правом углу сверху. 98% поддержки в РФ вас устраивает? Заодно узнаем, что Opera Mini не поддерживает это свойство